# 15.04 hung while configuring xsane

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

After trying a bunch of things, killed the dpkg process thinking it was just updating xsane but it killed the entire upgrade process after 2/3 of it was completed. System no longer boots. I am creating a 15.04 DVD and I'll reinstall but do I need to first backup user files? Most likely I do but I would like to confirm.